# MYSQL SELECT in SELECT query with large data: request timed out

Tags: mysql, large-data

The following query working well with small amount of data, but with larga data, I get 1001 The request timed out error.
I need this query before I want to order by switch.
Can anybody some better solution?

```
 SELECT t.azon, 
        parent_id,
        tul, 
        nev, 
       szures,( SELECT EXISTS ( 
                               SELECT * 
                               FROM 1_tulajdonsagkoto tk 
                               WHERE tk.tulajdonsag_id = t.azon AND tk.termek_id = 1238 LIMIT 1)) AS switch 
FROM 1_tulajdonsagok t 
LEFT JOIN 1_tulajdonsagkat k ON t.parent_id = k.azon
```

Comment: Can you provide, table descriptions,  some data and expected result, run explain for your query?

Comment: It solved when I reindexing all used fields

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT EXISTS
 (SELECT *
  FROM 1_tulajdonsagkoto tk
  WHERE tk.tulajdonsag_id = t.azon
    AND tk.termek_id = 1238
  LIMIT 1)) AS SWITCH
```

This make N+1 query problem. So we have 2 solutions:

- Move this into another query in codes. And you can map the "SWITCH" value in codes.
- Move this query into a temporary table before main query, and then left join main query into the temporary table.